# How to instantiate a class which normally needs parent(TWinControl) in a dll?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have to make use of the component dynamically which normally have the visual part.
That visual part can be turned off, but when I create the component it needs parent.

I have to use the component in a dll library. Is it possible and how to workaround the problem? How can I pass parent?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try creating a hidden window and making that the parent? For example `AllocateHwnd` will get you a window.

Comment: what do you mean by "parent" ? what is the real relationship? show the code. Also why cannot you use normal BPL instead of DLL ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you post some code ..? I need a parent of TWincontrol class. How Could I make use of the created handle?

Comment: Do you really need a `Parent`? Isn't it enough to have a parent window handle. Can't you use `CreateParented` to create your control? If you absolutely need a `Parent`, then create one. Just create a control that's not visible and use that. Very hard to offer code when we don't really understand exactly what this component needs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, createparented did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what component this is, but it seems to me a bad idea to use a visual component for invisible operations. Isn't there a better alternative?

Comment: @GolezTrol Unfortunately no. This is a commercial pdf viewer. it has the function to render the content of the page onto canvas as well it can also display the pdf in his area. I just need to render the choosen content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hidden window handle, for example with [`AllocateHWnd(nil)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd). And then create your control by calling [`CreateParented`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CreateParented) passing that hidden window handle.